# Use case for rank-3 (or higher) polymorphism?

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, higher-rank-types, parametric-polymorphism

I've seen a few use cases for rank-2 polymorphism (the most prominent example being the [ST monad](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad/ST)), but none for a higher rank than that. Does anyone know of such a use case?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I may be able to help, although such beast are inevitably a bit involved. Here's a pattern I sometimes use in developing well-scoped syntax with binding and de Bruijn indexing, bottled.

```
mkRenSub ::
  forall v t x y.                      -- variables represented by v, terms by t
    (forall x. v x -> t x) ->            -- how to embed variables into terms
    (forall x. v x -> v (Maybe x)) ->    -- how to shift variables
    (forall i x y.                       -- for thingies, i, how to traverse terms...
      (forall z. v z -> i z) ->              -- how to make a thingy from a variable
      (forall z. i z -> t z) ->              -- how to make a term from a thingy
      (forall z. i z -> i (Maybe z)) ->      -- how to weaken a thingy
      (v x -> i y) ->                    -- ...turning variables into thingies
      t x -> t y) ->                     -- wherever they appear
    ((v x -> v y) -> t x -> t y, (v x -> t y) -> t x -> t y)
                                                 -- acquire renaming and substitution
mkRenSub var weak mangle = (ren, sub) where
  ren = mangle id var weak         -- take thingies to be vars to get renaming
  sub = mangle var id (ren weak)   -- take thingies to be terms to get substitution
```

Normally, I'd use type classes to hide the worst of the gore, but if you unpack the dictionaries, this is what you'll find.

The point is that `mangle` is a rank-2 operation which takes a notion of thingy equipped with suitable operations polymorphic in the variable sets over which they work: operations which map variables to thingies get turned into term-transformers. The whole thing shows how to use `mangle` to generate both renaming and substitution.

Here's a concrete instance of that pattern:

```
data Id x = Id x

data Tm x
  = Var (Id x)
  | App (Tm x) (Tm x)
  | Lam (Tm (Maybe x))

tmMangle :: forall i x y.
             (forall z. Id z -> i z) ->
             (forall z. i z -> Tm z) ->
             (forall z. i z -> i (Maybe z)) ->
             (Id x -> i y) -> Tm x -> Tm y
tmMangle v t w f (Var i) = t (f i)
tmMangle v t w f (App m n) = App (tmMangle v t w f m) (tmMangle v t w f n)
tmMangle v t w f (Lam m) = Lam (tmMangle v t w g m) where
  g (Id Nothing) = v (Id Nothing)
  g (Id (Just x)) = w (f (Id x))

subst :: (Id x -> Tm y) -> Tm x -> Tm y
subst = snd (mkRenSub Var (\ (Id x) -> Id (Just x)) tmMangle)
```

We implement the term traversal just once, but in a very general way, then we get substitution by deploying the mkRenSub pattern (which uses the general traversal in two different ways).

For another example, consider polymorphic operations between type operators

```
type (f :-> g) = forall x. f x -> g x
```

An `IMonad` (indexed monad) is some `m :: (* -> *) -> * -> *` equipped with polymorphic operators

```
ireturn :: forall p. p :-> m p
iextend :: forall p q. (p :-> m q) -> m p :-> m q
```

so those operations are rank 2.

Now any operation which is parametrized by an arbitrary indexed monad is rank 3. So, for example, constructing the usual monadic composition,

```
compose :: forall m p q r. IMonad m => (q :-> m r) -> (p :-> m q) -> p :-> m r
compose qr pq = iextend qr . pq
```

relies on rank 3 quantification, once you unpack the definition of `IMonad`.

Moral of story: once you're doing higher order programming over polymorphic/indexed notions, your dictionaries of useful kit become rank 2, and your generic programs become rank 3. This is, of course, an escalation that can happen again.

Comment: Somehow I knew that Conor would be the one to answer this question :-)

Comment: Well, I'm used to replacing functions on simple types by indexed families of functions on dependent types, so wherever rank 2 shows up in "normal" life, I'm expecting rank 3. But will I be the only one to answer this question..?

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps the best ending to an abstract I've read yet: ["Multiplate only requires rank 3 polymorphism in addition to the normal type class mechanism of Haskell."](http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2841). (Oh, only rank-3 polymorphism, no big deal!)

Comment: Wow, _in addition_ to the type class mechanism!